# Ошибка при установке laravel-ide-helper

Tags: php, laravel, composer

```
$ composer require --dev barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
Using version ^2.9 for barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper[dev-master, v2.9.0, ..., v2.9.1] require illuminate/console ^8 -> found illuminate/console[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper 2.9.x-dev is an alias of barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper dev-master and thus requires it to be installed too.
    - Root composer.json requires barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper ^2.9 -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper[v2.9.0, v2.9.1, 2.9.x-dev (alias of dev-master)].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.5",
        "intervention/image": "^2.5",
        "itelmenko/laravel-mysql-logger": "^0.1.14",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^2.0",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^3.13",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^7.37"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mnabialek/laravel-sql-logger": "^2.2",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: `require illuminate/console ^8 -> found illuminate/console[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require` - поставьте `illuminate/console` через `composer update` и решите проблемы установки уже этого пакета, а потом вернитесь к IDE-шному. Вообще правильно было бы приложить весь `composer.json`

Comment: @TotalPusher уже обновлял. composer.json приложил

Comment: Все ставится. Снесите `composer.lock` и установите все заново. Но что-то может поломаться именно в вашем коде, так как либы будут обновлены.

Comment: @TotalPusher уже делал так. Не помогло

Comment: Удалите .lock, vendor и кэш.

Comment: Удалял и .lock и vendor. А какой кэш?

Comment: `composer clear-cache`

Comment: @TotalPusher не помогло

Comment: Может текущая версия хелпера не поддерживает версию лары? Попробуйте установить более старую.

Answer (score 1):

Устанавливаемый Вами пакет имеет зависимость от `illuminate/console ^8`, но установить его composer не может, т.к. у вас уже есть, по крайне мере один, установленный пакет с зависимостью от `illuminate/console` с более низкой версией и не допускающий ее повышение до версий `^8`

Вы можете посмотреть список установленных пакетов, имеющих в свох зависимостях `illuminate/console` и их требования к его возможным версиям:

```
composer why illuminate/console
```

Варианты по согласованию требований, предъявляемых пакетами к версиям `illuminate/console`:

1. Попытаться понизить версию пакета `barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper`
2. Попытаться повысить версию пакета, имеющего зависимость от `illuminate/console` и блокирующего установку пакета `barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper`